# HLint-like tool for F# code?

Tags: f#, lint

HLint is a command line static analysis tool for Haskell code, that even suggests the appropriate refactored version of the code. Anyone know of similar command line tools for linting F# code?

Comment: I don't know of any lint like tools - although this project https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas aims to be able to reformat code to match some set of rules.

Comment: Does Haskell have warnings built into the compiler?  I customarily compile my F# code with the warnings as high as they'll go and that helps catch some issues.

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer:**

No, there is no such tool yet.

**Long answer:**

*Let's discuss how to build it then.*

I did some background research which might be useful.

### References

There are a few lint tools in functional languages, which can be used as sources of inspiration. However, they tend to go to different directions.

[HLint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) is an advanced tool and its refactoring capability is amazing. Refactoring suggestion is more tricky in F# due to (1) F# code might have side effects so equational reasoning is unsound (2) When doing point-free transformation, value restriction could eliminate some good suggestions. If we accept false positives, it might become a bit easier.

In Scala's world, you have [Wart Remover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) and [Scala Style](https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle). The former focuses on common functional programming mistakes in Scala. The latter has its focus on human errors and inconsistencies (e.g. naming, convention, etc.). I guess Wart Remover is more relevant to F# as it is a functional-first programming language. However, a style checker tool is useful on a big code base with multiple developers.

The most relevant lint tool for F# is probably OCaml's style checker, [Mascot](http://mascot.x9c.fr/index.html). It has a big and extensible rule set. Many of these rules are applicable to F# with minor adaptation.

### Resources (and the lack thereof)

What we have:

- F# compiler is on GitHub. The relevant component - [F# compiler service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service) has a NuGet package so bootstrapping is easy. F# compiler source code is a good resource since F# compiler's warnings are very good and informative.
- There are recent works using F# compiler e.g. language binding, refactoring, code formatting, etc. so we have experience to build up on.
- We have other lint tools to learn from.

What we don't have:

- Good documentation on recommended styles and practices in F# is missing. [The design guideline](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf) has been useful, but it isn't complete enough.
- Building lint tool is time-consuming and difficult. Even with simple and single-purpose tool like Fantomas; it takes a lot of time to process F#'s ASTs in a correct way.

To sum up, if we define a right scope, creating a simple yet useful tool for F# is within reach.

### Updates

There is an actively-developing linter for F# available at https://github.com/duckmatt/FSharpLint. It seems that my analysis is not too far off :).

Comment: All of this is possible, but we would need a few serious contributors to the project and a good few months to built it out.

Comment: That is a tough requirement. It would be easier if one or two contributors build a baseline and ask others for contribution.

Comment: The main problem is its probably quite a bit of work, I have trouble getting people to contribute to the F# binding, never mind building an analysis tool.  The only hope is find someone with quite a lot of free time on their hands or maybe a Google summer of code project next summer.